# How to store validator errors into an object with Laravel and Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, validation

I am using Laravel 7 and Vue.js 2.
I made a form that should show a table if every field has been inserted.
I made also a server-side validation to check if all fields are correctly inserted.
This is the function that creates a call to the server with Axios:

```
        runReport: function() {
            const url = "api/get_report?room="+this.formReport['room']+"&participant="+this.formReport['participant']+"&start="+this.formReport['start']+"&end="+this.formReport['end'];
            axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.data);
                this.meetingsReport = response.data.data;
                alert('viva');
                this.$emit('passMeetings', this.meetingsReport);
                this.$emit('success');
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error.response.data);
                this.errors = error.response.data; //problem
                alert('noviva');
                
            });
        }
```

This is the validator in the controller:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'room' => 'required',
        'start' => 'required',
        'end' => 'required',
        'participant' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response($validator->errors(), 422);
    }
```

If everthing has been correctly inserted in the form I have no problems, but if I missed a field I am unable to store the errors in an empty object that I created called `errors`.

UPDATED: This is the response from the validation failed (status 422):

```
{
    "room": [
        "The room field is required."
    ],
    "participant": [
        "The participant field is required."
    ]
}
```

I suppose the problem is that I am unable to access to `this.errors` from the catch block of Axios.

Comment: Laravel will return a 422 response if a validation fails, so you should try to access the errors in the catch block `error.response` should contain the validation errors.

Comment: In reality I receive status 200. The alerts that I visualize when the validator fails are alert('call correct') and then alert('call failed'). I updated the question.

Comment: For any validation errors, as per convention it should return 422 status - unprocessable entity. So you could do `return response($validator->errors(), 422)`; And then access the errors in the catch block - most likely it would be under the `error.response.errors` key however you can check

Comment: I changed the validation return at 422 status. The key in the catch block is `error.response.data`. By the way I am unable to store the errors in a component data object because I receive the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'errors' of undefined`. Maybe the problem is that Axios is unable to see vue data objects using `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the context of an anonymous function doesn't point to the vue instance, so you may need to bind `this` to the function or use arrow function within the catch block

```js
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
    this.errors = error.response.data; //should not be any - problem
    alert('noviva');
                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved using the keyword self in the axios call. In this way I was able to connect the catch block with Vue.js component.

This is the code:

```
        runReport: function() {
            let self = this;
            const url = "api/get_report?room="+this.formReport['room']+"&participant="+this.formReport['participant']+"&start="+this.formReport['start']+"&end="+this.formReport['end'];
            axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.data);
                this.meetingsReport = response.data.data;
                alert('viva');
                this.$emit('passMeetings', this.meetingsReport);
                this.$emit('success');
                this.errors = {};
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error.response.data);
                self.errors = error.response.data;
                self.$emit('failure');
            });
        }
```